# In this guide: https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/guides/providing-liquidity/the-full-contract

Tags: solidity, uniswap, hardhat

Testing it on a mainnet fork  gives me:   `Error: missing argument:  in Contract constructor (count=0, expectedCount=1, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.4.0)` Not really sure what the problem is as I am passing in an argument to the constructor. If I need to initialise it how do I do so? Is the issue creating an instance that is connected to the one of the mainnet? I am testing mainnet fork. The code is in the guide, as I have it copied almost word for word.

Comment: Share the relevant part of your code, otherwise it's hard to figure out what could be the problem.

Comment: ``INonfungiblePositionManager public immutable nM;
      constructor(INonfungiblePositionManager _nonfungiblePositionManager) {
        nM = _nonfungiblePositionManager;
    }`` This is on the liquidity uniswap tutorial. Everything else is copied. @FrancoVictorio Thanks

Comment: Please update your question. Include this signature, but also the code that is deploying the contract. Try to make your question as complete and detailed as possible.

Comment: I copied this code word for word: https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/guides/providing-liquidity/the-full-contract  look here as it breaks the word limit. As mentioned above, I am using a mainnet fork and I only have set up some accounts and .deploy. Should I link my tests and hardhat config or what by deploy do you mean? Thanks a lot @FrancoVictorio